# ¿Cómo subir fotos al servidor y mostrarlas en un JSP?

Tags: java, imagen, jsp

Tengo un problema con una ruta absoluta en java jsp para subir fotos al servidor.

La foto la logro subir dando la ruta absoluta.

El problema es que el en HTML al poner la ruta de la imagen en el `src=""` no la va leer.

El localhost para que me lea la imagen debería ser
`http://localhost:8080/foto.png` que esto es en la ruta `C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot` pero la imagen me llega a la ruta absoluta que es esta en   `C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`.

La diferencia es una carpeta afuera y si concateno para modificarla y dejar un dato quemado (harcodeado) cuando suba el `.war` al servidor me generaría error porque el dato que yo queme tal vez no exista arriba.

No se que manera puedo realizar esto para insertar imágenes en una ruta y que el html las lea con la ruta de url `http://`

La ruta la estoy obteniendo asi:

```
public static String rutaFoto(String nombrefoto) {
        File filefotos = new File(nombrefoto);
        return filefotos.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una función, desde tu controlador obtienes request.getPart("nombre de input file"); y puedes guardar el nombre de la imagen concantenando la url. Saludos

```
private void guardarImagenes(Part filePart) throws IOException {
     String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName())
                            .getFileName().toString();

   String path = "C:\\Payara\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\docroot\\";
    File uploads = new File(path);
    uploads.mkdirs();

    File file = File.createTempFile("", fileName, uploads);

    try (InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream()) {
        Files.copy(input, file.toPath(), 
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        copyImage(file.getPath(), file.getPath());
    }
}
```